# Transparency and information in regard of visitors origin suggestion, use of site per origin

Tags: discussion, feature-request, community, site-evaluation

Valued community caretaker and Brahmas of this realm,

Not out of reason SE (of course for the most out of interest in merely low gain and interest in business) supplies with statistics of user origin. Not out of reason, SE does not prefer a "closed community", and so the Buddha didn't create a "closed up community" which separates casts, subjecting them as a matter of birth, stand.

Therefore it would be good if the Brahmas of this realm give ways to get the flow better known, and share, like suggested, statistics they actually know and, because not really skilled, not really having understanding of the benefit of giving and non-stinginess, others might wise enough to put into the proper even without holding power or formal position, working for their on liberation and that of many.

My person, as far as perceived, would declare this community as a "closed up one", domested by people neither skilled in worldly prosperity, nor above and beyound. My person says that it is a "householder occupied community" of self-interests above interests in gaining and giving release and naturally , in such situation, destinated to decay as fast as having been grown.

*(Note that this is not given for trade-, exchange-, stacks-, entertainment-sake itself but as means to escape this wheel)*

Comment: I think you're saying the SE has "information re visitor's origin" which means geolocating users by their IP address, is that so? And that SE has (is supplied with with) that information but doesn't publish it (make it better known)? And that that SE should publish that information, is that what you're asking?

Comment: And if so do you mean "statistics" about all users, about visitors (who read but don't use the site), and/or about specific individual users?

Answer (score 0):

Some information is available described here -- [What are site analytics?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) -- and can be seen by users with a reputation of 5000 or more.

There's no geolocation data there.

I'm allowed to share a summary of what it says.

There is "data derived from Google Analytics collected in the previous month".

- Most of the visits via search engines are via Google (not via other search engines) -- not much surprise.
- Most of the visits via links are from links within the Buddhism.SE site -- no surprise
- The second most "important" referring site is Philosophy.SE -- 1500 visits from Philosophy.SE compared with 4200 visits from Buddhism.SE -- that *does* surprise me, i.e. I'm surprised that's so high compared with Buddhism.SE

There is also data about the amount of traffic, the oldest data is February 2018.

- The number of posts, questions, answers, votes, has been approximately constant -- it varies a lot from week to week but I don't seen an up or down trend
- The amount of traffic seems to have decreased slightly:

  - "page views" from about 4000 to about 3500 (per day)
  - "visits" from about 2500 to about 2200
  - "new visits" from about 2000 to about 1000

Comment: See also [Geolocation statistics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331413/139866)

Comment: There's also a "Location" field in each user's profile but -- not every user supplies this information -- I guess it isn't aggregated as "statistics" -- that doesn't count visitors (i.e. readers who aren't users with a profile)

Comment: Also a lot of visitors from the physics site.